# iReport returns no data how to display static message

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have designed a report using iReport 4.5 and Oracle stored procedures that returns ref cursors.

When I pass a correct parameter the report successfully returns data. all good till now.

When I pass a incorrect parameter the iReport designer displays No Data to display message so
I changed the report property **"When No Data"** to **"All Sections, No Detail"** - all good till now.

But my business requirement is to display a dummy band with a message stating "**No Data to Display**" and this band will display only when the stored procedures returns no records and this band should not display when the stored procedure returns data.  how do i do that...

Thanks for your help with this.

Meeza

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the **"When No Data"** option you can also use the **"No Data Section"** option. That will then only show the **"No Data"** section of the report when there are no records returned. The only issue with this is that you will lose any other headers that are in the rest of the report. You can work around this by creating a main report with all of the headers/footers needed then create a subreport that contained the query for the records and the **"No Data"** section.

Comment: Actually with the "When No Data" to "All Sections, No Detail"  I am getting the desired results all my report headers and footers are getting displayed but the only addition to that what I want is I want to add a dummy group band that will be displayed only when there is no data returned with the message "No data to display" by the report and suppressed when there is data in the report.

Comment: When using the "No Data" in "When No Data" I got a blank band and I was able to add the desired text message... thanks for your help with this obscuredlogic

Comment: Sorry I cannot find "No Data", is it a property or value of a property.

I can see property "When no Data" and possible values in drop down I can see are:
"All sections, No detail", "Blank page", "No Data Section" and "No Pages"

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it works great. To:Net Surgeon ... "No Data" band (it is one of Bands, like Detail, etc.) is shown in Report Inspector for current shown report.